# Making a pre-populated form a HTML table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a prepopulated form that pulls values from any selected row in a HTML table . The HTML page is populated by a JSP .

my table looks like this

```
<table id="data-table" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>
            <th>value3</th>
            <th>value4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="class1"><%= value.valueOne() %></td>
            <td id="class2"><%= value.valueTwo() %></td>
            <td id="class3"><%= value.valueThree() %></td>
            <td id="class4"><%= value.valueFour() %></td>
        </tr>
        <%
        }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to obtain a prepopulated form with the row values on click of a particular row . I have some js code that does this .

```
$(document).on("click", ".data-table .class1", function(e) {
    var value =  $(this).closest('tr').val();
    console.log(value);
    // Just to check if I get the correct value 
});
```

unfortunately I cannot understand how to get the values for that particular row from the DOM and populate it in a form , That I want to overlay over the table . I would appreciate any pointers . I really would have written more code but I dnt know Jquery and am stuck

Comment: You should be logging value not comsumerID also if you click on class1 are you trying to return the value of that td?? Im not seeing any tr that will have a value you could use

Answer (score 1):

Your general strategy should be this:

- Populate the table on the server side: **done**
- Have the form pre-existing in the page, but hidden with css (`display:none`)
- Register a click listener on all `tr` elements to:

  1. find the values inside each `td` within the `tr`
  2. select the corresponding form inputs
  3. populate the inputs using jQuery's `val(value)` function.
  4. unhide the form if it's hidden

With this in mind, I would change your click listener from document to something like this. (Note: I'm assuming `value.valueOne()` are just numbers or strings, and don't contain any html.

```
//target just TR elements
$('tr').click(function(){
  values = [];
  $(this).children().each(function(){
    //add contents to the value array.
    values.push($(this).html())
  });

  //fill in the form values
  populateForm(values);
});
```

Populate form would completely depend on your form's HTML, but to get you started here's an idea of what it might look like:

```
function populateForm(values){
  //set the value of the input with id of name to the value in the first td.
  $('#name').val(values[0]);
  //show the form (id inputForm) now that it's populated
  $('#inputForm').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things are wrong with your html markup and your JQuery selector.  You'll never be able to execute the code you've provided...

1. You have two 'id' parameters in this element, `<table id="data-table" id="test">`...  This will work with the JQuery I've fixed below, but it's malformed html either way.
2. In your selector, you are using the syntax for finding an element based on it's css class attribute, however your elements in your HTML have those values set as 'id' attributes.  Thus, this, `$(document).on("click", ".data-table .class1", function(e) {`... should be written as follows, `$(document).on("click", "#data-table #class1", function(e) {`

Now, if you are attempting to get the values within all of the 'td' elements within a row, then all you really need to do is get the parent element of the 'td' that was clicked, and then get it's children.  Then, for each child, get their values.

Like this...

```
$(document).on("click", "#data-table #class1", function(e) {
    var elements =  $(this).parent().children();

    $.each(elements, function(index, el){
        alert($(el).html());
    });
});
```

I've saved a JSFiddle for you to see this in action...  http://jsfiddle.net/2LjQM/

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is used to return value of form inputs. You are using it to try to get the value of a row and row has no `value`.

Without seeing what your output into the TD as html, I assume it is a form control

Try

```
$(document).on("click", ".data-table .class1", function(e) {
    var value =  $(this).find(':input').val(); // `:input pseudo selector wull access any form control input,select,textarea
    console.log(value);
    // Just to check if I get the correct value 
});
```

EDIT: if the TD contains text

```
 var value =  $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scraping the DOM, you could invert the logic, and build the rows using javascript instead. Check out this jsBin to see the solution in action: http://jsbin.com/aligaZi/2/edit?js,output

Start with an empty table:

```
  <table class="data-table" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>
            <th>value3</th>
            <th>value4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since you need to fill a form with the data, I'll be using a simple one as an example:

```
<form class="data-form">
  <label>Value1<input class="value1" /></label>
  <label>Value2<input class="value2" /></label>
  <label>Value3<input class="value3" /></label>
  <label>Value4<input class="value4" /></label>
</form>
```

Then, on the javascript side:

```
$(function() {
  // Interpolate the values somehow.
  // I'm not familiar with JSP syntax, but it shouldn't be too hard.
  // I will use dummy data instead.

  var tableData = [
    {
      value1: "row1-v1",
      value2: "row1-v2",
      value3: "row1-v3",
      value4: "row1-v4"
    }, {
      value1: "row2-v1",
      value2: "row2-v2",
      value3: "row2-v3",
      value4: "row2-v4"
    }
  ];

  // For each object, create an HTML row
  var rows = $.map(tableData, function(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append($('<td class="class1"></td>').html(rowData.value1));
    row.append($('<td class="class2"></td>').html(rowData.value2));
    row.append($('<td class="class3"></td>').html(rowData.value3));
    row.append($('<td class="class4"></td>').html(rowData.value4));

    // When this row is clicked, the form must be filled with this object's data
    row.on("click", function() {
      fillForm(rowData);
    });

    return row;
  });


  $(".data-table").append(rows);

  function fillForm(rowData) {
    var form = $(".data-form");

    form.find("input.value1").val(rowData.value1);
    form.find("input.value2").val(rowData.value2);
    form.find("input.value3").val(rowData.value3);
    form.find("input.value4").val(rowData.value4);
  }
});
```